# Laurent Series with Assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to obtain the Laurent of the function `f(z) = 1/(z(z-1))` valid first in `0 < Abs[z] < 1` and second in `Abs[z] > 1`. I tried

```
Series[f[z], {z, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> (0 < Abs[z] < 1)]
```

obtaining the correct result, but when I change the Assumptions

```
Series[f[z], {z, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> Abs[z] > 1]
```

I obtain the same result, which is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Series[1/(z*(z - 1)), {z, Infinity, 4}]`.

Comment: It works. I ask however what's the use of Assumptions in series of complex functions...

Answer (score 1):

Up to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html), the `Assumptions` option of the  `Series` command works for parameters only. The required expansion can be produced by

```
Series[1/(z*(z - 1)), {z, Infinity, 4}]
```